# No access to files when booting from USB

Tags: permissions

My Ubuntu has been screwed up somehow so I am booting from a USB to save my data. However, I can't access some files and folders. I get this error:

> This location could not be displayed.You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of “  ”.

Does anyone know how I can access these files?

well,, let me try to explain little bit more.. it is difficult to explain because I don't know what is happening here. I don't know much about using terminal. so I am just using the mouse to do everything. When the usb boot start I click the icon of files and I found a folder that there are my saving date from my old ubuntu.In devises 495GB... after clicking this there is the folder name is home/user/..... In this user holder I found the my old date. but the amount of all files shows only 3gb instead of 200gb and I cant open some of folders. I cant access some picture folder. but I don't know exactly because some pictures I can see it.

Comment: What files? Where are they? On the USB?On your hard drive? How are you accessing them? Through the file manager? The command line? Please [edit] your question and add a specific example of a file you cannot access.

Comment: thank you for editing my question. I am trying to save my date form head disk that I saved when my Ubuntu was still working. I can access some files and folders. but I cant access some pictures and videos.

Comment: OK, please [*edit*] your question and explain how you are doing this. From the GUI (using the mouse)? From the terminal? What is the difference between the files you can access and those you cannot? Are they in different locations? You need to give as much detail as you can. It is impossible to help you with what you've told us.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your trying to pull files from the hdd using the live usb so you can reinstall...

If that is the case i would try to use sudo chmod 777 " dir " -R which will give all users access to the files in " dir "

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it this comand but terminal said

Comment: chmod: cannot access ‘ ---- ’: No such file or directory 
I did wrong way to put file name??

Comment: Lets say i just want to change premissions on my whole home dir. Id run sudo chmod 777 /hdd_mount_point/home/user_home_dir -R

Comment: I think I am typing wrong about location of file but I dont know how I can type... when I click the file icon there is "Divices" place and on the list of the Divices, there is a Divice"/495 GB Volume"so I typed

Comment: sudo chmod 777 /495 GB Volume/home/use_dir -R

Comment: i apologize  for my poor descriptions. if you where to open your file manager as root this should solve your problem. open a terminal and enter " gksu nautilus " this should open  a file manager as root and should give you access to your files.